# View filter if field contains a value?

Tags: 7, views

I'm trying to filter my view based on data in a single field. My field *targetuser* contains a string of numbers: 47,505,100,20.

I'm trying to setup the view so that if *targetuser* contains the logged in user ID (in this case, that's 47), the content should be visible.

> [image: The view's setup]

However, the setup I have now only works if a single number is inside that field, not four numbers.

How can I accomplish this?

Note, I've installed the *Views Argument Substitution* module. The settings for the second contextual filter I'm referencing are the following.

#### content:targetuser:provide default value: logged in user id

> [image: screenshot]

**Update:** For those wondering, the existing Contextual Filters so far do the following:

Show node if:

- Content: Author uid (logged in user is also the author of the node)
- Content:targetuser (if target user is equal to logged in uid)OR IF
- Content:targetuser (if target user field is equal to 9506)

Comment: What type of a field is the Target user field? text, integer, entity reference? It doesn't seem that Views Argument Substitution can help you in your case, it filters results, not validation criteria, and you seem to want to hide the views depending on this filter. You might need some custom code to extract the comma-separated values from a text field if that's your case. Why do you have 3 contextual filters? They all need to be satisfied at the same time and it's very difficult to construct something that works. You can follow that module instructions to filter out the views results.

Comment: @prkos target user field is a textfield. Would this work if it were an integer field?

Comment: If you're considering changing your structure I think it makes the most sense to have it Entity reference field that actually references users.

Comment: Just realized I'm unable to change my structure... the text field already holds existing data :/ @prkos That said, my contextual filter that uses targetuser = logged in user id works perfectly...so I'm not sure why comma separated values would be an issue? Any other tricks I could try?

Comment: Please update the question with that information, how does targetuser field work? If it works what are you actually asking? Text field is a text field, it's not numbers separated by commas, it's all just text characters. You'd have to do some custom code to parse that text as if it were comma separated numbers and pass that to the contextual filter, then it could work.

Comment: @prkos Out of curiosity: Could this not be accomplished by putting a PHP line into my Contextual Filter for targetuser? E.g. instead of targetuser = logged in user id, could i not select the php option and write a method that says if targetuser contains uid?

Comment: Although going directly to PHP this way isn't the most recommended approach I think it can be done, yes. But the trick is in "if targetuser contains uid", that isn't a oneliner AFAIU. If your field contains number 45 it might match the UID 4 and UID 5, because it contains them! And user 4 is not the same as user 45! You need to extract the number from _in between_ commas, it's no longer the same "Contains" function as you see in Filters. But try it and see what you get, report back with your result.

Comment: Are you trying to control access to the entire view based on the presence of the current user's uid in the field, or just part of the view?